# Open only 1 tab without recursion

Tags: jquery, window.open

I have this function below:

```
function trHoverClick() {

    jQuery('.grid tr td').click(function(){

        var link = jQuery(this).parent('tr').find('a.edit').attr('href');
        window.open(link);

    });
}
```

What is called when updating the data ta table by ajax.

Sometimes it happens that you open 1 to 3 tabs to contain recursion, wanted to know if you have a way to tell which will always open only one tab and not until 3.

Comment: couldn't understand....

Comment: How many `a.edit` tags are in the `tr`? I expect there are more than one, so you need to determine which to open.

Comment: I have 1 button to edit listing in all three, when I click on a link tr caught him and open a tab, sometimes have recursion and reaches open 3 tabs

Comment: Hang on, how many times do you call `trHoverClick()`? Only once I hope.

Comment: How is `trHoverClick()` invoked?

Comment: Jack worked his editing this? @Jack

Comment: Send again for me checked window.open(link, 'edit'); @Jack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the problem is that clicks on different links open a new window each time and you only want to open them in a single window.

Simple, give your window a name:

```
window.open(link, 'my_window');
```

When called with different locations it will open them in the same window (if it already exists).

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
function trHoverClick() {
    jQuery('.grid tr td').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();

        var link = jQuery(this).parent('tr').find('a.edit').attr('href');
        window.open(link);
    });
}
```

the issue might be it is propagating with the click method.

Comment: The OP might not mean that.

Comment: @Dexxtz, can you please add your HTML code in your question.